# the rolling regression in R using roll apply

Tags: r, rollapply, rolling-computation

My imported data contains 7 variables: `Y` and `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4`, `X5`, `X6`. I tried applying the `rollapply` function in `zoo` in order to run a rolling regression within an in-sample with a window of 262 obs. (work days in a year).

```
         date             Y            X1            X2
1     10/1/07 -0.0080321720  4.690734e-03  3.333770e-03
2     10/2/07  0.0000000000 -2.818413e-03  5.418223e-03
3     10/3/07  0.0023158650 -4.178744e-03 -3.821100e-04
4     10/4/07 -0.0057491710 -5.071030e-03 -8.321550e-04
5     10/5/07  0.0073570500  3.065045e-03  5.179574e-03
6     10/8/07  0.0127708010 -7.278513e-03  1.145395e-03
7     10/9/07  0.0032661980  9.692267e-03  6.514035e-03
8    10/10/07  0.0013824430  1.161780e-04  2.676416e-03
9    10/11/07  0.0026607550  1.113179e-02  8.825719e-03
10   10/12/07 -0.0046362600 -2.453561e-03 -6.584070e-03
11   10/15/07 -0.0023757680 -7.829081e-03 -3.070540e-03
12   10/16/07 -0.0128673660 -4.619378e-03 -8.972126e-03
13   10/17/07  0.0016049760  1.276695e-03  5.349316e-03
14   10/18/07 -0.0044198970 -9.018499e-03 -1.215895e-02
15   10/19/07 -0.0011080330 -5.328661e-03 -7.131916e-03
16   10/22/07 -0.0024217970 -2.019539e-02 -2.021072e-02
17   10/23/07  0.0031270520  1.668604e-02  2.236130e-02
18   10/24/07 -0.0040367400 -1.061433e-02 -5.735703e-03
19   10/25/07  0.0001011170  1.346312e-02  1.036109e-02
20   10/26/07  0.0003032910  3.766526e-03  2.903628e-03
21   10/29/07  0.0004042450  1.416406e-02  2.527754e-03
22   10/30/07 -0.0012132240 -1.387166e-03 -8.202236e-03
23   10/31/07  0.0057497510  9.593904e-03  1.433401e-02
24    11/1/07 -0.0032238590 -1.648975e-02 -1.029199e-02
25    11/2/07 -0.0031330560 -7.737784e-03 -7.559498e-03
26    11/5/07 -0.0001012300 -7.877763e-03 -8.500554e-03
27    11/6/07 -0.0004050220  7.407770e-03  2.536320e-03
28    11/7/07 -0.0031444970 -5.904219e-03 -8.026064e-03
29    11/8/07 -0.0045822590 -3.712574e-03 -6.395584e-03
30    11/9/07  0.0016316540 -1.432552e-02 -1.741458e-02
31   11/12/07 -0.0019378860 -3.926583e-03 -4.543370e-03
32   11/13/07  0.0011223920 -1.952799e-03 -2.622112e-03
33   11/14/07  0.0008154940  8.687550e-06  1.085682e-03
34   11/15/07  0.0015272620 -1.549745e-02 -1.556172e-02
35   11/16/07 -0.0001017450 -5.578556e-03 -1.432244e-02
36   11/19/07  0.0014234880 -2.206707e-02 -3.537936e-02
37   11/20/07 -0.0010165700  1.643937e-02  5.140822e-03
38   11/21/07 -0.0008140010 -1.715961e-02 -2.756704e-02
39   11/22/07 -0.0008146640 -2.108098e-03  7.455698e-03
40   11/23/07  0.0008146640  1.266776e-02  1.615338e-02
41   11/26/07  0.0008140010  5.539814e-03  2.854080e-03
42   11/27/07  0.0006100660 -8.561106e-03 -9.720505e-03
43   11/28/07 -0.0015258640  3.392103e-02  2.132374e-02
44   11/29/07 -0.0006109980  6.109848e-03  1.045556e-02
45   11/30/07  0.0004073730  9.214342e-03  1.133690e-02
46    12/3/07 -0.0002036660 -7.006415e-03 -6.079820e-04
47    12/4/07  0.0002036660 -1.187605e-02 -2.554853e-02
48    12/5/07  0.0007125040  1.362121e-02  9.525618e-03
49    12/6/07 -0.0034655010  7.917348e-03  5.252105e-03
50    12/7/07  0.0018361730 -1.026832e-02  1.216898e-02
51   12/10/07  0.0013240310  3.347302e-03  1.143687e-02
52   12/11/07  0.0005087760 -3.433720e-03  2.373558e-03
53   12/12/07  0.0024385300  5.507930e-04  3.191504e-03
54   12/13/07 -0.0115336820 -1.793698e-02 -2.149447e-02
55   12/14/07 -0.0010271160 -2.307745e-03 -1.038483e-03
56   12/17/07 -0.0033969870 -1.822079e-02 -2.920662e-02
57   12/18/07  0.0000000000 -1.873297e-03 -7.061215e-03
58   12/19/07 -0.0004125410 -3.372400e-06 -7.879850e-03
59   12/20/07  0.0008249120 -6.227957e-03 -1.752460e-04
60   12/21/07 -0.0020635580  1.734991e-02  1.348190e-02
61   12/24/07  0.0003098050  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
62   12/25/07  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
63   12/26/07  0.0001032470  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
64   12/27/07  0.0006192590  5.006783e-03  5.274480e-03
65   12/28/07 -0.0005160230  6.428153e-03  8.557260e-03
66   12/31/07  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
67     1/1/08  0.0002064410  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
68     1/2/08 -0.0009293200 -6.023384e-03 -3.104400e-03
69     1/3/08  0.0027853730 -2.302511e-03 -2.759650e-03
70     1/4/08  0.0018526150 -2.149450e-02 -2.645257e-02
71     1/7/08 -0.0005142710 -4.445206e-03 -2.117698e-

1596          <NA>         <NA>          <NA>
```

the last line for some reason doesn't show the values,even though there are in the original excel file(X3,X4,X5,X6 are missing,since the columns are stacked on top of each other,I copied the batch from the top for the example.

My code is:

```
rollapply(ts, 262, lm(
          Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+0, subset=1:floor(length(x)/2)), 
          align="right")
```

The error message I get is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Y' not found
```

I really wonder why it can not find the `Y` variable, since it is displayed in the time series dataset with the appropriate heading.

Comment: The third argument of `rollapply` is supposed to be a function, but you're calling `lm`, referring to an undefined value `x`, and not passing a `data=` argument.

Comment: The question does not state precisely what output is needed but assuming that you want to store the coefficients for each regression there is an example of this in the examples section of the `rollapply` help page in the zoo package:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-3/topics/rollapply

Answer (score 12):

It is not really clear what your data actually is (use `dput(example_data)` to give reproducible examples).

But the `lm` call in your example is simply doing the same regression over and over again (your x is not changing) and as josilber points out, it is supposed to be a function. Here is an example where all the data is in the data.frame `allRegData` and it has at least two columns, one named `y` and another named `x`:

```
require(zoo)
rollapply(zoo(allRegData),
          width=262,
          FUN = function(Z) 
          { 
             t = lm(formula=y~x, data = as.data.frame(Z), na.rm=T); 
             return(t$coef) 
          },
          by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help,the code worked, but I got a lot of NAs in the middle of the output,I used XLConnect package to export the output to an excel file with:                        writeWorksheetToFile("results of rolling window in R.xlsx",data=results,sheet="rollapply",header=TRUE)                    I get the following error message:                     
Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space                    Could that be solved somehow?

Comment: The `NA` could be caused by a not invertible model matrix (i.e. determinant zero) -> do your `X1` and `X2` show enough variance across observations, are there no duplicates, are there NAs ? Write your output to a csv file with `write.table` or `write.csv` to exclude any issue with you XLConnect package. If you have another question: pose it in a new question.

Answer (score 7):

I guess your questions are

1. that you want to apply rolling regression on 262 width window of data for roughly 6 years yielding 1572 which is close to your 1596 observations with six covariates.
2. figure out how to solve your problem with `rollapply`.
3. an issue with loading in a data set from Excel.

It seems hard to help you with 3. since you do not provide the data set or the R code you use. Starting with 1., then you can use the `rollRegres` package I have made. What you would do is something like this

```r
#####
# simulate data
width  <- 262L
n_yr   <- 6L
n_covs <- 6L
set.seed(23847996)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n_yr * width), ncol = n_covs, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("X", 1:n_covs)))
df <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(n_yr * width), X)
head(df)
#R         Y     X1     X2     X3      X4     X5      X6
#R 1 -1.1478  0.516 -1.381  0.776 -0.0992  1.254 -0.8444
#R 2 -0.0542  1.328  1.411 -1.206  0.2560  0.975  0.9534
#R 3 -0.8350 -1.402  1.190  0.591 -1.5928  0.330  1.0806
#R 4 -0.5902  0.937 -0.182  0.193  0.1575  0.217 -0.2613
#R 5  1.7891 -0.608 -1.090  0.180 -1.1765 -0.992 -0.8831
#R 6  2.0108  0.259 -0.129  0.261  1.6694 -1.822  0.0616

#####
# estimate coefs
library(rollRegres)
fits <- roll_regres(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, df, width = width)
tail(fits$coefs) # estimated coefs
#R      (Intercept)     X1      X2      X3     X4      X5      X6
#R 1567    0.006511 0.0557 -0.0243 0.00907 0.0234 -0.0370 -0.0553
#R 1568    0.005816 0.0569 -0.0233 0.00798 0.0248 -0.0370 -0.0560
#R 1569    0.006406 0.0566 -0.0231 0.00814 0.0243 -0.0385 -0.0555
#R 1570    0.004898 0.0519 -0.0213 0.00773 0.0323 -0.0391 -0.0588
#R 1571    0.002922 0.0532 -0.0211 0.00809 0.0307 -0.0377 -0.0609
#R 1572    0.000771 0.0538 -0.0262 0.00580 0.0309 -0.0363 -0.0658
```

Now, regarding 2. then you can do something like [what Hans Roggeman shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23163104/5861244) but a version that works with multiple regression as you request

```
library(zoo)
c2 <- rollapply(
  df, width = width, function(z){
    coef(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, as.data.frame(z)))
  }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_, align = "right")
all.equal(fits$coefs, c2, check.attributes = FALSE) # gives the same
#R [1] TRUE
```

It is much slower though

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rollRegrs = roll_regres(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, df, width = width),
  rollapply = rollapply(
    df, width = width, function(z){
      coef(lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6, as.data.frame(z)))
    }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA_real_, align = "right"), times = 25)
#R Unit: milliseconds
#R       expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
#R  rollRegrs    1.73    1.98    2.31    2.37    2.64    3.01    25
#R  rollapply 1726.74 1798.37 1881.25 1834.00 1964.62 2178.58    25
```

The `rollapply` version can be faster if you use `lm.fit` but it it still slower than `roll_regres`.

Comment: There is any chance you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268864/how-to-perform-rolling-regression-in-r-with-this-dataset)?

Comment: Hi Benjamin is it possible to calculate the t and p value for every regression that is made with roll_regres? This would help me so much.