# How to perform rolling regression in R with this dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, zoo

Let's suppose I have the following dataframe made of up 219 rows. The dataset is not perfectly monthly for some structural reasons.

```
df = structure(list(X1 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X2 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X3 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X4 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X5 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X6 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X7 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86), X8 = c(0.67, -1.45, 0.01, -1.07, -0.8, 0.21, -0.27, 
0.44, 1.09, 0.99, 0.62, -0.43, -0.29, -0.57, -1.1, 0.18, 0.26, 
0.38, -2.38, 0.79, 0.11, 0.03, 1.02, 0.02, 0.33, 1.03, -0.41, 
-1.46, -0.06, 1.95, -1.04, -0.95, 1.61, 0.46, -0.6, -1.42, -0.8, 
0.92, 0.84, -1, 1.55, -0.86, 0.58, -0.35, 1.13, 0.39, -0.71, 
-0.67, 1.47, -0.01, 0.09, -1.19, 0.22, -1.8, -0.59, 1.06, -1.05, 
1.42, -1.91, 0.73, 0.75, 0.82, -0.69, -0.52, 1.1, -0.56, -0.52, 
1.16, -0.35, -0.71, 0.92, -0.01, 0.89, -0.06, 0.87, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.38, 0.95, -0.23, -0.43, -1.17, 0.65, -0.76, 2.12, -0.16, 2.21, 
1.06, -0.35, 0.44, -0.46, 1.56, 1.66, -0.51, 1.08, -0.81, 0.71, 
1.08, 0.79, -0.44, 0.92, -0.03, -0.15, -0.25, -0.48, 0.28, -0.86, 
-1.07, -2.52, 0.15, -0.5, 1.13, 1.94, -0.35, -0.3, -0.12, -0.04, 
2.48, -0.3, -0.28, -3.04, 0.68, 1.02, -1.07, 1.59, -0.11, -0.44, 
1.27, 0.1, -0.1, 1.32, 0.08, 1.24, 1.46, 0.33, 1.55, -0.87, 1.26, 
-0.56, 0.76, -0.51, -0.24, -0.94, 0.88, -0.08, -2.27, 1.09, 1.15, 
-1.59, -0.65, 1.22, 0, 1.49, -2.03, 0.16, 0.21, 0.25, -2.21, 
1.43, 0.67, -1.33, 0.06, -0.34, 0.15, 1.93, -0.94, 0.21, -0.97, 
-0.95, -0.43, 1.86, 0.96, -0.32, 0.69, -0.54, 0.16, -0.04, -0.78, 
1.39, -0.39, -0.52, -0.82, -0.51, -0.18, -0.38, -0.68, 0.44, 
1.38, -0.27, 0.63, -0.56, 0.12, -1.02, 1.59, -1.03, -0.77, -0.17, 
-0.89, 0.56, -0.22, 1.43, -0.55, 0.69, 0.82, -0.32, 0.55, -0.94, 
0.31, 0.55, 1.11, -0.54, 0.58, -1.49, 2.33, -1.45, 1.05, 0.28, 
1.68, 0.86)), row.names = c(NA, -219L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then, what I want to do is setting up a rolling regression in a time window that encompasses, say, 2 years (24 months). To do so, I run the following codes:

```
library(rollRegres)
library(zoo)

roll_model1 = roll_regres(X1 ~ ., df, 24L, do_compute = c("sigmas", "r.squareds"), do_downdates = TRUE)

roll_model2 = rollapply(df, width = 24, FUN = function(x) coef(lm(X1 ~ ., data = as.data.frame(x))), by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
```

In the first case, the model doesn't work. In the second case, I only get results for the intercept (and only coefficinets). Besides, I don't understand why there are 196 coefficient observations.

Can anyone help me run a rolling regression over 2 years window with this dataset?

Thanks!

Comment: You get an error with message `'dchdd' failed with code -1` from `roll_regres` as all your columns are identical as [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63269137/5861244) mentions. Thus, your design matrix is singular. The `roll_regres` function throws an error in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All columns of `df` are the same

```
all(df == df[, 1])
## [1] TRUE
```

so it can perfectly predict X1 using X2 and the others are not needed so it gives NA.

Regarding the `rollapply` code it only gave coefficients because that is what you asked for `coef(lm(...))` .  Your function should return a vector of whatever it is you want to get out.

It does a regression for rows 1:24, rows 2:25, ... rows 196:219 so clearly there are 196 such sets so the result has 196 rows.  If you specify `fill=NA` then it will pad it with NAs to give the same number of rows as `df`.

Note that `rollapplyr` is available which defaults to `align = "right"`.

Here is a possible function that returns a variety of information:

```
library(broom)

stats <- function(x) {
  fm <- lm(X1 ~., as.data.frame(x))
  c(coef(fm), unlist(glance(fm)))
}
rollapplyr(df, width = 24, FUN = stats, by.column = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is much clearer now. If I only want to get out, R^2, p-values and coefficients, how would you modify the code?

Comment: Have added a possible function to return a variety of statistics.

Comment: Thanks a lot! super helpful!