# How to Loop linear regression repeatedly for n rows in R?

Tags: r

I am currently working on a dataset that looks like this

| Streamflow | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 24 | 25 | 43 | 44 |
| 198 | 30 | 45 | 66 | 54 |
| 285 | 32 | 39 | 54 | 47 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | .. |

all the way down 4408 rows in total.
What I want to do is conduct linear regression of `streamflow ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4` from row 1 to row 20, then from row 2 to row 21, and the from row 3 to row 22, till the end so that I can get a set of coefficient every run. I know that I might need `for`to start the loop, but I just cannot figure out how to have it work on every 20th rows. Any suggestion will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(CFbasin)) {
  y <- CFbasin[i:(i+20), 2]
  x1 <- CFbasin[i:(i+20), 3]
  x2 <- CFbasin[i:(i+20), 4]
  mod_coef[i] <- coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2))
}
```

So this is what I wrote and it doesn't give me the ideal results

Comment: You probably do not need a loop, but you should provide enough of your data using `dput()` that we can demonstrate how to do what you want. Also 4408 is not divisible by 20 so what happens to the leftover 8 rows of data? As a start, `idx <- rep(1:220, each=20)` would identify 220 groups of 20 lines each.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say that clear enough, my bad, the reason why I think I need `for` loop is that I need 1:20 to regression, then 2:21, and then 3:22 and repeat this process so on.

Comment: see rolling regression https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162937/the-rolling-regression-in-r-using-roll-apply/52457815

Comment: Thank you, the rolling regression works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach using the `iris` data set also:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Since there are 150 rows, we compute the number of rolling groups of 20 and use that to create a matrix with 20 rows and 131 columns listing the row numbers to be used in each regression:

```
rows <- nrow(iris)
last <- rows + 1 - 20
idx <- sapply(1:last, seq, length.out=20)
str(idx)
#  num [1:20, 1:131] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

So we have 131 columns and each column identifies a group of 20 rows for a regression. Now compute the 131 regressions and save the coefficients:

```
results <- lapply(1:131, function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris[idx[, x], ]))
coeffs <- t(sapply(results, coef))
head(coeffs)
#      (Intercept) Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# [1,]  0.88165253   1.1027541    0.4335847  -1.3039612
# [2,]  0.64094220   1.1111668    0.6186075  -1.4860753
# [3,]  0.28030724   1.2120241    0.6477881  -1.7022181
# [4,] -0.01943516   1.1879500    0.8971728  -1.6773764
# [5,]  0.46106345   0.9888293    0.9230228  -0.8457783
# [6,]  0.92206667   0.9734378    0.5716684  -0.5058189
```

Each regression is stored as a list in `results` so that the first regression is `results[[1]]`.

```
summary(results[[1]])
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, 
#     data = iris[idx[, x], ])
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -0.26396 -0.17137 -0.00562  0.13582  0.36386 
# 
# Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)    0.8817     0.6730   1.310    0.209    
# Sepal.Width    1.1028     0.1748   6.309 1.04e-05 ***
# Petal.Length   0.4336     0.3448   1.257    0.227    
# Petal.Width   -1.3040     0.7924  -1.646    0.119    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.204 on 16 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.8078,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7717 
# F-statistic: 22.41 on 3 and 16 DF,  p-value: 5.666e-06
```

Getting a statistic computed by `summary` is slightly more involved:

```
Rsq <- sapply(results, function(x) summary(x)$adj.r.squared)
# quantile(Rsq)
#        0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
# 0.1635166 0.4471409 0.6298927 0.8417655 0.9278258
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, if I understand correctly what you mean:

1. Until this line `mutate(group20rows = as.integer(gl(n(), 20, n())), .before=1) %>%` it is only preparation of fake data
2. Create a sequence of 20 with your desired column.
3. group and apply `group_split`, then you have these groups of data each 20
4. apply `map_dfr` to iterate over each group your regression
5. use `glance()` from `broom` package to show all in one dataframe in a tidy from

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

colnames1 <- c("streamflow", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")

iris %>% 
  select(-5) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length1 = Sepal.Length) %>% 
  rename_with(~colnames1) %>% 
  mutate(streamflow=streamflow*100) %>% 
  mutate(group20rows = as.integer(gl(n(), 20, n())), .before=1) %>% 
  mutate(group20rows = as_factor(group20rows)) %>% 
  group_by(group20rows) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(streamflow ~ x1+x2+x3, data = df) %>% 
      glance() %>% 
      add_column(group20rows = unique(df$group20rows), .before=1)
  })
```

output:

```
  group20rows r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic     p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
  <fct>           <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 1               0.808         0.772  20.4     22.4  0.00000567      3  -86.5 183.   188.    6662.          16    20
2 2               0.335         0.210  26.2      2.69 0.0815          3  -91.4 193.   198.   10961.          16    20
3 3               0.873         0.850  32.0     36.8  0.000000207     3  -95.5 201.   206.   16420.          16    20
4 4               0.511         0.419  34.4      5.57 0.00819         3  -96.9 204.   209.   18919.          16    20
5 5               0.530         0.442  30.0      6.01 0.00609         3  -94.2 198.   203.   14417.          16    20
6 6               0.877         0.854  28.0     38.0  0.000000165     3  -92.8 196.   200.   12502.          16    20
7 7               0.787         0.747  32.5     19.7  0.0000128       3  -95.8 202.   207.   16895.          16    20
8 8               0.644         0.466  28.0      3.62 0.0845          3  -45.0  99.9  101.    4719.           6    10
```